# Simple Vue calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator, vue.js

I made conditional calculator in Vue js but I need help to make it more efficient.

https://jsfiddle.net/wbrx9cyp/1/

*example of code:*

```
essentialPackage(){
  this.essentialToggle = true;
  this.mediumToggle = false;
  this.extraToggle = false;

  if(this.shortToggle && this.essentialToggle){
    this.packagePrice = 1.2;
  }else if(this.longToggle && this.essentialToggle){
    this.packagePrice = 39;
  }

},
```

I made it best I could, but there are too many **if statements**

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately your question is off-topic as of now, as the code to be reviewed must be [present in the question](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1308). Code behind links is considered non-reviewable. Please add the code you want reviewed in your question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Introduction

Based on your JSFiddle, you have code with multiple responsibilities stored in one area. Separate them.

I've written some examples below in TypeScript, however the same ideas can be translated to JavaScript easily.

## If Statements

To answer the question about too many if statements, make a calculator component that takes in each parameter and returns the result. I've added an example below.

## Class Design

### Term Design

Perhaps Term could be a class that ShortTerm and LongTerm extend.
I'm not sure exactly what the difference is in pricing between ShortTerm and LongTerm, but they should have a price/rate. Just a price different from each other.

```
 class Term {
  price: number;
  constructor(price: number) {
      this.price = price;
  }
}

class ShortTerm extends Term {
  constructor() {
    super(1.5);
  }
}

class LongTerm extends Term {
  constructor() {
    super(1.2);
  }
}
```

### Package Design

We can further specialise our packages.

```
// Forced to use Pack as Package is a keyword.
class Pack {
  price: number;
  constructor(price: number) {
    this.price = price;
  }
}

class Essential extends Pack {
  constructor() {
    super(1);
  }
}

class Medium extends Pack {
  constructor() {
    super(1.5);
  }
}

class Extra extends Pack {
  constructor() {
    super(1.9);
  }
}
```

### Calculator Design

Now that we have some parts of our insurance offer neatly organised, we can create a class dedicated to calculation.

```
class Calculator {
  public calculate(term: number, pack: number) {
    return term * pack;
  }
}
```

## Putting it all together

Now we have two insurance variables, and a calculator. Lets put it all together.

```
const shortTerm = new ShortTerm();
const medium = new Medium();
const calculate = new Calculator().calculate;


const offer = calculate(shortTerm.price, medium.price)
console.log(offer); // Ouput: 2.25
```

## Conclusion

Given that we've designed our 3 components (Terms, Packs, Calculator), we're able to delegate all our calculation logic to one simple function.

We can further design our Offers as a class, given they might have a client (person who bought the offer), expiry date, each insurance variable, and some methods like editOffer() which changes a variable from shortTerm to LongTerm.

## Note

While a lot of the classes are the same with just a price variable, there may be specific differences between a package, a term, etc.

Unfortunately I don't have the specifics to know what the differences are. However you can still apply all these principles to improve your software design and increase your codes efficiency.

Comment: This seems to be a review of code that's not in the question.  Remember that on Code Review, we can only review code that's actually presented for review (any other code is outside of our change-tracking, for one thing, so your review could be invalidated without warning).  Prefer instead to work with the author to fix the question so that it can be properly answered.

Comment: I'm sure it wouldn't be too hard for Ivan to post complete code for review - hopefully he'll be able to do that at leisure while the question is closed (preventing other inadvertent answers until it's ready), and then re-open it for reviews.

Comment: We do appreciate your enthusiasm to educate others!  I wouldn't like you to find your efforts get wasted, hence the suggestion to help get the question on-topic before you answer it.